# Store Ascii Values

Tags: c

how to store Ascii character a to z in any one type of variable using strcpy?

```
for(i=97;i<122;i++)
{
    for(j=97;j<122;j++)
    {
        printf("%c%c",i,j);
        int a = strcpy(i,j);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the ASCII value of "XY" ??

Comment: `strcpy` handles `char*` not char or int. See http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcpy/

Comment: @Pheonix - you mean 'xy'?  Or XYZZY?

Comment: For a single character, `strcpy` doesn't make any sense at all. Like the name implies, its purpose is to copy (null terminated) strings of unspecified length.

Answer (score 2):

```
char a[3] = {0};

for(i=97;i<122;i++)
{
    for(j=97;j<122;j++)
    {
        printf("%c%c\n", i, j);
        a[0] = i;
        a[1] = j;
        printf("%s\n", a); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So (assuming ASCII):

```
char str[27]={0};
char temp[2]={0};
int i;
for (i='a';i<='z';i++) {
 temp[0]=i;
 strcpy(str,temp);
}
```

But do you really need to use `strcpy`?

Answer (score 0):

> Ηow to store Ascii character in any one type of variable using `strcpy()`?

You don't need it, since for a single character `strcpy()` is unnecessary.

Moreover, you try to handle an `int` with [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/), whereas this function handles `char*`.

---

What you could do is something like this:

```
char myarray[3] = {0};
for(i = 97; i < 122; i++)
{
    for(j = 97; j < 122; j++)
    {
        printf("%c%c\n", i, j);
        myarray[0] = i;
        myarray[1] = j;
        printf("%s\n", myarray); 
    }
}
```

where I used a char array, since if you store the ASCII character in an `int` you cannot expect it to print the same character, as it was stored in a `char`. Even if you try [Convert char array to a int number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204471/convert-char-array-to-a-int-number-in-c), you will not be able to succeed in it.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it easily using type cast inside your loop

```
int num = 97;
char a = (char)num;   // 'a' = 97 casting int to char 
num = (int)a       // num = 97 cast 'a' to ASCII
```

let it try

Comment: Are you sure about the casts?

Comment: yes, its works for char. cause when you trying to cast a char to int , it return this char's ASCII value.

Comment: Again, are you sure that the right way to cast int to char, is `(int)num` ?

Comment: there is no need to cast when assigning integers to integers.

Comment: signed char holds an ascii value naturally.  A correct cast would be (char) num;

Answer (score -2):

```
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    char c = '\0';
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    a = c + 0;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Output: ASCII value of entered character.

I have provided the the code. Please refere it.
Why this is So?
Focus on the addition operation which is assigned to the int variable a. During compilation of this operation compiler finds that the variable c is of char type but; the operator + is next to it and hence compiler uses the ascii value of the character stored in c variable.

I hope it will helpful  for you. Thank you.

Comment: Please post code as actual text, not images. Also, not only `+0` doesn't do anything here, but the `int a;` is not necessary. You could print `c` directly with `%d`.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The question is about to store the ascii value of the characters not to only print them. Ok? @HolyBlackCat  I hope you will read the question again.

Comment: I think I have provided the correct solution to store the ascii value. But don't  know why my answer got two dislikes?