# How do I convert multiple elements of a character array into an integer?

Tags: c, char, integer, type-conversion

Say I have,

```
char x[0] = '1';
char x[1] = '2';
```

I need to 'concatenate' these two into an integer variable,

```
int y = 12;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Many will disagree so I just put it into a comment:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Using simple math: `int y = ((x[0] - '0')  * 10) + (x[1] - '0');` (Note `'0'` means ASCII of digit `0`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char array to a int number in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204471/convert-char-array-to-a-int-number-in-c)

Comment: @BenceKaulics because [`atoi` doesn't return any error message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714), [`strtol`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7021725/995714) is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way, if it's really only two digits and you don't want to "go up" (in complexity) to a string in order to use string-conversion functions, is to just compute it directly using the basic structure of a number. Each digit is worth 10 times more than the one to its right.

```
const char x[2] = { '1', '2' };
const int value = 10 * (x[0] - '0') + (x[1] - '0');
```

This will set `value` to `12` by computing `10 * 1 + 2`.

The subtraction of `0`, meaning "the numerical value of the digit zero in the target's character encoding", works since C requires the decimal digits to be encoded in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you terminate `x` with a NULL-terminator you can use `atoi`.

[Example](http://ideone.com/z22XKk):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char x[3];
    x[0] = '1';
    x[1] = '2';
    x[2] = '\0';
    int x_int = atoi(x);
    printf("%i", x_int);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C++, the question is about C.